# Jade to Dust Parser?

Tags: node.js, pug, dust.js

I recently wrote using Jade Template for NodeJS. When talking with my manager.. I found that we use Dust within company. Thus I was required to switch over to dust.

While following the DRY principle.. I don't want to do this manually.

Is there good translator/parser to parse existing Jade template to Dust? I searched online but didn't found.

Additionally, if there's no such template, what about I go and implement one myself? I took compiler course before and thinking this would probably be not-to-hard to implement. But I never tried... and don't really understand the Dust template yet. how do you think of the difficulty of doing one parser myself?

Comment: that's not following the DRY principle, that's being lazy. Which we all are :p.